# MomentJS is comparing dates differently on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, momentjs

I want to group the events by day. In the development environment (Brazil) it does the group correctly, but on the server (USA) is not. Its's putting the events that take place at the end of the day at the beginning of the next day. I imagine that is related to the timezone.

The dates of the events are in the following format:

> 2016-11-03T18:00:00-0200

Below is my code, I tried a few things to solve this problem but could not. I'm using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to handle dates.The events must be grouped by the day regardless of the timezone, offset or anything else.

```
const events = [];
_.forEach(ungroupedEvents, event => {
    const date = moment(event.start_time, moment.ISO_8601);
    const period = _.find(events, period => date.isSame(period.date, 'day'));
    if (period) {
        period.events.push(event);
    } else {
        events.push({
            date: date.format('L'),
            events: [event]
        });
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this? I am all day and it does not get any progress. :(

Comment: "The events must be grouped by the day regardless of the timezone, offset or anything else." - do you mean you want to ignore the timezone, so that 2016-01-01T23:00:00 (1st Jan 2016, 11PM UTC time) and 2016-01-01T23:00:00-0200 (1st Jan 2016, 11PM UTC-2 time, but actually 2nd Jan 2016, 1AM UTC time) are treated as the same time? Technically speaking, they aren't the same time (the latter is two hours after the former, and thus crosses midnight and falls on the following day).

Comment: How could I make it based on a specific timezone?

Comment: If you want time zones ignored, then you have to select one to use for everything, e.g. GMT. For times in a timezone -0200, any time between 00:00 and 03:00 will be between 9pm and midnight the day before in a time zone -0500 (east coast USA, aka EST).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `moment-timezone` and verify at each step that dates are formatted as UTC and input/output correctly for the right timezone (UTC/GMT).

Or, and I think this is best, use getTime() to get MS since epoch, store and group using that big number (you can use mod % to get day since epoch).